# Dynamically change app's content by current day

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, facebook

I'm developing an app (using *HTML / PHP / Java Script*) for Facebook.

When the app is opened, there is button Start. After clicking, it should show some pictures.

App duration is from 1st of December to 25th of December.

Each day after clicking `Open` It should show different image. For example on 1st of December should show 1.jpg, on 2nd of December should show 2.jpg and so on.

What is best way to achieve It? Should I create *Cron Job*? Should I create separate files for everyday? 1.php, 2.php and etc? Or I have to create game.php and add there different `DIVS` for everyday and with *Java Script* show required `DIV` for current day?

Index.html looks like:

```
<div id="main" class="main">
    <img src="images/background.png" alt="Christmas Game" class="background_main">
    <input type="image" src="images/start.png" alt="Start Game" class="start_btn" onClick="parent.location='game.php'" />
</div>
```

By click button from index.html It should redirect me to correct content of current day.

Game.php looks like this:

```
<div id="main" class="main">

    <img src="images/day1/game.png" alt="Christmas Game" class="game">

    <a href="downloads/coupon.jpg" download="coupon.jpg" title="Prize Coupon">

        <img src="images/day1/download.png" alt="Download Coupon" class="download">

    </a>            

</div>
```

Somehow I need to make It dynamic that everyday opened different images / pages.

If something unclear - ask me, I will try provide more details.

Comment: In which way are your images stored? Like 1.png, 2.png etc?

Comment: I'm thinking to make It 1.png, 2.png and so on, but maybe there will be problems with security, users will see 1.png on first day, 2.png on second day, so they can try to check for 25.png to know what prize will be on 25th of December. I want that someone suggested me why how to make It in most secure way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple and secured way to do it. What I would suggest you to do is, to save all the image files with an encrypted name. You can use php `hash` function to generate a complex hash which would be impossible to break.

Generate 25 images names in this way.

```
$imgName = hash('sha512', '1'); //this would generate a complex hash, which would be for pic 1.png
$imgName = hash('sha512', '2'); //this would generate a complex hash, which would be for pic 2.png
```

Now using php, you can easily display these images. Look at this.

```
<?php
//get today's date.
$currentDate = date('d'); //24 - current date
$imgName = hash('sha512', $currentDate).".png";//now this would generate a really long file name, which will be impossible for a user to guess
?>

<!-- Now to display the image, just do this -->
<img src="yourimagedirector/<?php echo $imgName; ?>">
```

My code first gets the current date, then builds up the fileName (like we stored before), then fetches it up and shows it. Simple, fast and secure!

Comment: Also have tried your method It generating hash: `c0033b5f5a4815a172984d64037dd49a8663fb8b3a71e47f11ecd332c8c3819c57e1631fdf46d66c6ff0e58763a61529fefcfa2a6675e186ee901e5452fedd94` for `24`. So It can't find `24.png` image should be named `c0033b5f5a4815a172984d64037dd49a8663fb8b3a71e47f11ecd332c8c3819c57e1631fdf46d66c6ff0e58763a61529fefcfa2a6675e186ee901e5452fedd94.png` in this way showing image. So I have to rename images with hash names?

Comment: @Infinity Correct. Rename with that hash which is generated for each file. So the new file name would be `hashgenerated.png`. 
Then, you can easily access it and display by the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jQuery.

1. First you need to give name to image like that (e.g. -> day1, day2, day3...day25).
2. Use this code:

   ```
   var startDate = new Date('11/23/2015'); // MM/DD/YYYY format 
   var date2 = new Date(); // get current day date
   var diffDays = date2.getDate() - date1.getDate(); 

   $('.start_btn').click(function(){
      $('.background_main').attr('src','day'+diffDays+'.jpg');
   });
   ```